# Problems installing ubuntu alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, dell, windows-10

I have a dell laptop (http://www.dell.com/br/p/inspiron-15-7559-laptop/pd?oc=cai7559w10he1715715brp020w1&model_id=inspiron-15-7559-laptop) with windows 10 home and I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows.

I have created a bootable USB stick of Ubuntu 16.04.1amd64 using Rufus and I have disabled the BIOS secure boot option. I have also freed the windows disk (200GB) to accommodate the Ubuntu OS.

Then, I rebooted windows and I tried to install Ubuntu from USB, so far so good. The problem begins when the Ubuntu installation guide appears. The first thing is that I can’t connect to the wifi network to get updates on the fly. But the greatest issue is that Ubuntu does not recognize that windows is installed.

I have tried to follow similar posts about installing Ubuntu alongside windows but I could not find a solution.

Can anyone, please, help me with that?

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch off fast startup in windows. Fast startup keeps windows partitions mounted when you shutdown windows, which is why ubuntu is not able to access it and recongnize windows.

Go to Control Panel > Power Option > Choose what power buttons do. In there click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable", scroll down and uncheck the "Turn on fast startup".

I hope this helps.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I just did what you suggested but I still cant install ubuntu.